# Babel is breaking remarks

Tags: babel

For some reason this is not working:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\begin{document}
    \begin{remark}
        remark
    \end{remark}
\end{document}
```

because of a "Missing { inserted."

But if I remove this line: `\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}` it's compiling normally.

How can I use both `babel` and `remark`?

Comment: The main language of your document is Hebrew. If you want to have English inserts in it, you have to properly segregate them for left-to-right typesetting.

Comment: But even if I add \selectlanguage{english} it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me in LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main, onchar=ids fonts]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{english}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX, Renderer=HarfBuzz }
\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures=Common,Scale=1.0]{TeX Gyre Schola}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}
          [Ligatures=Discretionary,
           Language=Default,
           UprightFont=*-Medium ,
           BoldFont=*-Bold ,
           ItalicFont=*-Medium , % Intentionally disable italics, which slant the opposite way.
           BoldItalicFont=*-Bold]{DavidCLM}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures=Common]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}
          [Ligatures=Discretionary,Language=Default]{Miriam CLM}
\babelfont{tt}
          {inconsolata}
\babelfont[hebrew]{tt}
          [Language=Default]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}       

\babeltags{hebrew=hebrew}
\babeltags{english=english}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\begin{document}
  \begin{english}
    \begin{remark}
        remark בעברית
    \end{remark}
  \end{english}
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Gyre Schola + David CLM sample]

In this example, I disabled italics in David CLM because they don’t mix well with italics that slant the opposite way, but you could enable them, or even add a `FakeSlant` to `ItalicFeatures` to get left-to-right italics.

You might remove the `onchar=` language options.  You would then have to tag your languages everywhere with `\begin{english}` or `\texthebrew`, instead of LuaLaTeX auto-detecting them.  You would,  however, get correct formatting when you write full paragraphs in English.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but I'd say there is a bug in `amsthm`. Try with the following redefinition after loading this package:

```
\makeatletter
\def\deferred@thm@head#1{%
  \if@inlabel \indent \par \fi % eject a section head if one is pending
  \if@nobreak
    \adjust@parskip@nobreak
  \else
    \addpenalty\@beginparpenalty
    \addvspace\@topsep
    \addvspace{-\parskip}%
  \fi
  \global\@inlabeltrue
  \everypar{\the\dth@everypar}% <<<<<<<<<< Changed
  \sbox\@labels{\normalfont#1}%
  \ignorespaces
}
\makeatother
```